# Random choice e shuffle com comportamentos diferentes

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Estou testando alguns códigos com o módulo `random` e notei uma diferença de comportamento entre `random.choice()` e `random.shuffle()`. A seguir os códigos que estou treinando:

```
import random

alunos = ['Fernando', 'Paula', 'João', 'Maria']

a = random.choice(alunos)

print(a)
```

E:

```
import random

alunos = ['Fernando', 'Paula', 'João', 'Maria']

random.shuffle(alunos)

print(alunos)
```

O estranho é que se eu uso o `random.choice()` sem colocá-lo na variável `a`, não funciona, ele retorna a lista inteira.

Já o `random.shuffle()` me dá o resultado esperado mesmo não estando em uma variável. Estou fazendo algo errado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) do módulo `random`, [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) retorna **um dos elementos da lista**, escolhido aleatoriamente. No seu primeiro código, esse retorno foi colocado na variável `a` (ou seja, ela contém apenas um dos elementos da lista). **Mas a lista em si não é modificada**, `random.choice` só pega um dos elementos e retorna.

> *O estranho é que se eu uso o `random.choice()` sem colocá-lo na variável `a`, não funciona, ele retorna a lista inteira.*

Se você não atribui o retorno de `random.choice()` a uma variável, seu valor é perdido:

```
# retorna um dos elementos da lista, mas este não é atribuído a nenhuma variável
random.choice(alunos)
print(alunos) # imprime a lista, sem modificações
```

Ou seja, a função retornou um dos elementos, mas onde ele foi guardado? Em nenhum lugar. E como `random.choice` não modifica a lista, esta permanece inalterada (na verdade a função não "retorna a lista inteira", o que acontece é que a lista não é modificada neste caso).

---

Já [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) embaralha a lista, modificando-a. Por isso você não precisa de uma variável para guardar o resultado, pois **a própria lista está sendo modificada dentro da função**.

Inclusive, `random.shuffle` retorna [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None):

```
print(random.shuffle(alunos)) # imprime "None"
```

Por isso nem faz sentido atribuir seu retorno a uma variável.

Enfim, existe essa diferença de comportamento justamente porque cada um faz uma coisa diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você não leu a documentação das funções:

`shuffle()` : Randomiza os valores nas posições da própria lista, ou seja, retorno na própria lista, que no caso é `alunos`, rodando duas vezes por exemplo, a:

```
1ª vez, teria resultado: alunos = ['Paula', 'Fernando', 'João', 'Maria']
2ª vez, teria resultado: alunos = ['Maria', 'Paula', 'Fernando', 'João']
```

`choice()` : Seleciona aleatoriamente apenas um único valor da lista inserida e retorna o valor escolhido para uma variável, que no caso seria `a`, rodando duas vezes por exemplo, a:

```
1ª vez: a = Maria
2ª vez: a = João
```

[Fonte sobre Shuffle()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_shuffle.htm)

[Fonte sobre Choice()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_choice.htm)